# Best Practice to Archive Old Data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb

I'm using a MySQL database to store logs from multiple servers. The database's growth on average is 50 GB per day. Its total size is now 1.7 TB.

It has `ID` and `datetime` columns.

I want to move data older than one week to another database on the same server.

**What are the steps needed for this?**

As of now I do this:

1. Create the Archive Database and table.
2. `Insert into ArchiveDB.table select * from old_tbl where datetime
   <= Archivedate`
3. Then `DELETE FROM old_tbl WHERE datetime <= Archivedate`

I want to implement this with the following conditions:

- Insert and delete via batches.
- Reclaim the space after deleting from the old database.
- Update stats without downtime.

...Or if you know of any best practice then let me know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With InnoDB and `PARTITIONs`, you could set up daily `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAY(...))` and use "Transportable tablespaces" to disassociate a day from the table and move it separately.  This will be a lot faster than the queries it would take to do the `INSERT...SELECT` and `DELETE`.  Once detached, the partition (now a table in its own right) can be moved to another database or server without impacting the ingestion of more data.

One drawback:  InnoDB's disk footprint is a lot more than Archive's.

What kinds of queries do you apply to the logs?

Blogs:
[*partitioning*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)
and
[*chunking lengthy deletes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks)

Comment: This is a good one, But unfortunately, we already deleted 30% for data (1 week). So I need to reclaim the space and update the stats.

Comment: Dropping a partition does not impact the stats on the rest of the table.  And it reclaims the space (assuming `innodb_file_per_table=ON`).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using a combination of [Percona's pt-archiver](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-archiver.html) (used to archive rows from a MySQL table into another table or a file) and [Percona's pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html) (can be run "online" with a neutral `ALTER` to reclaim the disk space, assuming you're running with `innodb_file_per_table=ON`).